# Break a text line inside a <pre> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, pre

I have a screen shot of my code snippet in chrome:

[image]

and in firefox:

[image]

My question is, how do I make the same effect in firefox as it was in chrome? the code snippet part is inside a pre tag. thanks a lot for any help! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cross browser wrapping:

```
pre
{
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, post millennium */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bcFX/)

Comment: I think you should have posted the source http://www.longren.org/wrapping-text-inside-pre-tags/

Comment: @Ahmad: I actually got this from one of my website design's CSS. And this snippet is all over the web anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 pre {
       white-space:normal;
       word-wrap: break-word;
     }
```